# Abordagem de subquery Self Join

Tags: sql-server, join

Tenho uma tabela de lista de presença, onde preciso uma lista onde identificando quem esteve presente:

Estrutura da tabela:

```
create table lista_presenca_usuario
(
   id int identity(1,1),
   usuarioId int,
   dia int,
   turno int,
   presente int
)

insert into lista_presenca_usuario 
(usuarioId, dia, turno, presente)
values
 ( 10,1, 1, 1)
,( 10,1, 2, 0)
,( 10,2, 1, 1)
,( 10,2, 2, 1)
,( 20,1, 1, 1)
,( 20,1, 2, 1)
,( 20,2, 1, 1)
,( 20,2, 2, 1)
```

#### Abordagem Nº1:

Faço uma tabela temporaria, e atualizo as linhas:

```
select 
  usuarioId
  ,cast('' as varchar(20)) as primeiro_dia_manha
  ,cast('' as varchar(20)) as primeiro_dia_tarde
  ,cast('' as varchar(20)) as segundo_dia_manha
  ,cast('' as varchar(20)) as segundo_dia_tarde
 into #tmpDadosExport3
 from lista_presenca_usuario
 group by usuarioId

update t
  set t.primeiro_dia_manha = case when lpu.presente = 0 then 'ausente' else 'presente' end
 from #tmpDadosExport3 t
 join lista_presenca_usuario lpu(nolock) on t.usuarioId = lpu.usuarioId
 and lpu.turno = 1 and lpu.Dia = 1 

update t
  set t.primeiro_dia_tarde = case when lpu.presente = 0 then 'ausente' else 'presente' end
 from #tmpDadosExport3 t
 join lista_presenca_usuario lpu(nolock) on t.usuarioId = lpu.usuarioId
 and lpu.turno = 2 and lpu.Dia = 1 


update t
  set t.segundo_dia_manha = case when lpu.presente = 0 then 'ausente' else 'presente' end
 from #tmpDadosExport3 t
 join lista_presenca_usuario lpu(nolock) on t.usuarioId = lpu.usuarioId
 and lpu.turno = 1 and lpu.Dia = 2

update t
  set t.segundo_dia_tarde = case when lpu.presente = 0 then 'ausente' else 'presente' end
 from #tmpDadosExport3 t
join lista_presenca_usuario lpu(nolock) on t.usuarioId = lpu.usuarioId
 and lpu.turno = 2 and lpu.Dia = 2
```

funciona mas, está oneroso,
estou tentando agora esta query

```
SELECT usuarioid, x.primeiro_dia_manha, x.primeiro_dia_tarde FROM lista_presenca_usuario y
inner join (
  select
   id
   ,case when turno = 1 and Dia = 1 then
                    case when presente = 0 then 'ausente' else 'presente' end
                    end AS primeiro_dia_manha
  ,case when turno = 2 and Dia = 1 then
                    case when presente = 0 then 'ausente' else 'presente' end
                    end AS primeiro_dia_tarde
  from lista_presenca_usuario
)x on x.id = y.id
group by usuarioid, x.primeiro_dia_manha, x.primeiro_dia_tarde
```

mas infelizmente, a mesma retorna linhas duplicadas, mesmo eu fazendo um group by.

#### Resultado esperado:

```
usuarioId|primeiro_dia_manha|primeiro_dia_tarde
10       |presente          |ausente           
20       |presente          |presente
```

#### O resultado que está vindo:

```
usuarioId|primeiro_dia_manha|primeiro_dia_tarde
10       |presente          |Null           
20       |Null              |presente          
10       |presente          |Null          
20       |Null              |presente
```

fiz um sql fiddle para ilustrar:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/fdb69/7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O primeiro passo é classificar as colunas agrupando por `usuarioId`, `dia` e `turno` utilizando um `CASE` para definir a descrição que será utilizada nas colunas posteriormente. Depois disso utilize o `PIVOT` para transformar as descrições em colunas. O resultado desses passos é o seguinte:

```
SELECT y.usuarioId,
       y.primeiro_dia_manha,
       y.primeiro_dia_tarde,
       y.segundo_dia_manha,
       y.segundo_dia_tarde
  FROM (SELECT lpu.usuarioId,
               CASE
                 WHEN lpu.dia = 1 AND lpu.turno = 1 THEN 'primeiro_dia_manha'
                 WHEN lpu.dia = 1 AND lpu.turno = 2 THEN 'primeiro_dia_tarde'
                 WHEN lpu.dia = 2 AND lpu.turno = 1 THEN 'segundo_dia_manha'
                 WHEN lpu.dia = 2 AND lpu.turno = 2 THEN 'segundo_dia_tarde'
               END AS classificacao,
               CASE MAX(presente) WHEN 1 THEN 'presente' ELSE 'ausente' END AS presenca
          FROM lista_presenca_usuario lpu
         GROUP BY lpu.usuarioId,
                  lpu.dia,
                  lpu.turno
  ) x
 PIVOT(MAX(x.presenca) FOR x.classificacao IN (primeiro_dia_manha,
                                               primeiro_dia_tarde,
                                               segundo_dia_manha,
                                               segundo_dia_tarde)) y;
```

---

Uma outra forma é agrupar pelo `usuarioId` e utilizar um `CASE` para verificar o conteúdo. Com o resultado dessa verificação pode-se classificar em `presente` e `ausente`:

```
SELECT lpu.usuarioId,
       CASE MAX(CASE WHEN lpu.dia = 1 AND lpu.turno = 1 THEN lpu.presente END) WHEN 1 THEN 'presente' ELSE 'ausente' END AS 'primeiro_dia_manha',
       CASE MAX(CASE WHEN lpu.dia = 1 AND lpu.turno = 2 THEN lpu.presente END) WHEN 1 THEN 'presente' ELSE 'ausente' END AS 'primeiro_dia_tarde',
       CASE MAX(CASE WHEN lpu.dia = 2 AND lpu.turno = 1 THEN lpu.presente END) WHEN 1 THEN 'presente' ELSE 'ausente' END AS 'segundo_dia_manha',
       CASE MAX(CASE WHEN lpu.dia = 2 AND lpu.turno = 2 THEN lpu.presente END) WHEN 1 THEN 'presente' ELSE 'ausente' END AS 'segundo_dia_tarde'
  FROM lista_presenca_usuario lpu
 GROUP BY lpu.usuarioId;
```

---

De qualquer forma acredito que uma coluna por composição de dia/turno é algo que, utilizando um período grande, será de difícil manutenção e pouco adaptável. Dependendo da sua necessidade talvez seja ideal rever a solução.

---

> [**Usando `PIVOT` e `UNPIVOT`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)
>
> Você pode usar os operadores relacionais `PIVOT` e `UNPIVOT` para alterar uma expressão com valor de tabela em outra tabela. `PIVOT` gira uma expressão com valor de tabela ao transformar os valores exclusivos de uma coluna na expressão em colunas múltiplas na saída, além de executar agregações onde forem necessárias em quaisquer valores de coluna remanescentes que sejam desejados na saída final. `UNPIVOT` executa a operação oposta a `PIVOT`, girando colunas de uma expressão com valor de tabela em valores de coluna.